# Transition between user control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I currently have 2 UserControls on my page. The first UserControl1 has a listbox which is bound to a collection. The other, UserControl2, will contain information based on the select from the listbox in UserControl1.

What I want is that UserControl2 is hidden until the user had made a selection from the ListBox and the page will transition from the list to the information.

What I am really looking for is a simple and easy to user control that will handle the transition. I prefer to get the look from Zune software where I can have a back button on UserControl2...

I am currently developing in .NET 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recreate a Zune-like UI using [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) [Screens & Conductors](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) for navigation:

- Having a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) named ActiveItem on View.
- Replacing ActiveItem on ViewModel using the [ActivateItem](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) Conductor.

For the swap out effect we did animate the ActiveItem using two triggers (raised from ViewModel on ActiveItem change). One trigger for the swap in and one for the swap out (what this animations do is no more than change the margin from an offset to its proper value with a little delay).

You can extend this method not only for the ActiveItem but for every control you want to swap out so I expect this'll give you an idea. As for passing the selected item from one control the other control [inject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) that value when using the ActivateItem within the ViewModel.